# Why does the sample space of a random variable not matter?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am self studying probability and statistics from the book "All Of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman.
The book says that the sample space $\Omega$ of a random variable $X: \Omega \to E$ doesn't matter.
What does this mean?

My interpretation of this was that given a random variable $X: \Omega \to E$, there exists $\Omega'$ (with probability measure $P'$), and a random variable $Y: \Omega' \to E$ such that $$PX^{-1}=P'Y^{-1}.$$

Is such statement even true though? I saw in a previous stack exchange question that is true when $X$ is discrete. What about in general? If so, how does one construct such $\Omega'$ and $Y$?

Moreover, is this even the reason that the sample space "doesn't matter"?

Often, I see random variables not explicitly given, but rather their CDF, PDF, or PMF (when discrete). How does one determine an $\Omega$ (up to cardinality) in these scenarios?

Comment: I think the author is trying to imply that the exact structure of $\Omega$ (ie, the elements of $\Omega$) doesn't matter since we can relabel the elements with some index set of cardinality $|\Omega|$, so if $\Omega=\{\textrm{"head","tails"}\}$, we can just relabel $\Omega$ as $\{0,1\}$ and talk about $P(\Omega=k)$ for $k=0,1$. What really matters is the probability measure on the sample space $\Omega$

Comment: How does one infer the cardinality of $\Omega$ though? A lot of examples in the book don't give $\Omega$ or $X$ explicitly, often only $PX^{-1}$. Is there a way to determine $\Omega$ up to cardinality from say a CDF, probability mass function, or PDF?

Comment: No, there isn't. A particular sample space $\Omega$ admits infinitely many probability measures. Also, two different sample spaces $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ can have the same probability measure. My point was that you don't really need to know the sample space explicitly.